# How does the wc -c in linux work?

Tags: linux, shell, wc

Why the number of characters is `4`?

```
echo abc|wc -c
```

Output

```
4
```

The output should be `3`, because the number of characters is `3`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its also counting the newline, try

```
[~]> echo -n abc|wc -c
3
```

`-n` tells the `echo` not to print a newline.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` add a line break at the end of its output, which is counted as a character by `wc -c`. You can use `echo -n` to omit the line break, and get the result you're expecting:

```
[mureinik@mureinik ~]$ echo -n abc | wc -c
3
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man wc`:

> wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

As the rest of the answers indicate, the new line is also counted as character.

See:

```
$ echo "abc" | wc
      1       1       4
                      ^
                      characters

$ printf "abc" | wc
      0       1       3
                      ^
                      characters
```